# What is a buffer overflow and how do I cause one?

Tags: c++, buffer-overflow, fortify-source

I have heard about a buffer overflow and I would like to know how to cause one.

Can someone show me a small buffer overflow example?
New(And what they are used for?)

Comment: Why are you trying to produce a buffer overflow?

Comment: see: gets in the C standard library.

Comment: "see: gets in the C standard library" - is this a joke?

Comment: @NTDLS: It is snarky, but completely serious...gets is dangerous, and completely indefensible in production code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A buffer overflow is basically when a crafted section (or buffer) of memory is written outside of its intended bounds. If an attacker can manage to make this happen from outside of a program it can cause security problems as it could potentially allow them to manipulate arbitrary memory locations, although many modern operating systems protect against the worst cases of this.

While both reading and writing outside of the intended bounds are generally considered a bad idea, the term "buffer overflow" is generally reserved for *writing* outside the bounds, as this can cause an attacker to easily modify the way your code runs. There is a good article on Wikipedia about [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and the various ways they can be used for exploits.

In terms of how you could program one yourself, it would be a simple matter of:

```
char a[4];
strcpy(a,"a string longer than 4 characters"); // write past end of buffer (buffer overflow)
printf("%s\n",a[6]); // read past end of buffer (also not a good idea)
```

Whether that compiles and what happens when it runs would probably depend on your operating system and compiler.

Comment: Buffer overflows are usually more destructive when you're writing beyond the end of a buffer rather than reading [e.g., char x[2]; strcpy (x,"hello");] - this is because it frequently stuffs up many other variables and/or the stack frame.

Comment: Don't have have to write past the bounds of the array for it to be considered a buffer overflow? In that case I think an example that changes the contents at a[200] would be better.

Comment: @david if you read the first paragraph of wikipedia's article that you cite, a buffer overflow only happen when you 'write' outside the bounds of a buffer, your sample is *not* a proper buffer overflow.

Comment: That still isn't a buffer overflow. a is a pointer to a string, and the 2nd line is simply changing that reference. Plus, a is an array so it's not even a valid l-value and you're code won't compile. A fool-proof example would be strcpy(a, "a string longer than 4 characters");

Answer (score 34):

Classical example of a buffer-overflow:

```
// noone will ever have the time to type more than 64 characters...
char buf[64];
gets(buf); // let user put his name
```

The buffer overflow alone does most often not happen purposely. It happens most often because of a so-called "off-by-one" error. Meaning you have mis-calculated the array-size by one - maybe because you forgot to account for a terminating null character, or because some other stuff.

But it can also be used for some evil stuff. Indeed, the user long knew this hole, and then inserts say 70 characters, with the last ones containing some special bytes which overwrite some stack-slot - if the user is really tricky he/she will hit the return-address slot in the stack, and overwrites it so it jumps forward into that just inserted buffer: Because what the user entered was not his name, but his shell-code that he previously compiled and dumped out. That one will then just executed. There are some problems. For example, you have to arrange not to have a "\n" in that binary code (because gets would stop reading there). For other ways that mess with dangerous string functions, the binary zero is problematic because string functions stop copying there to the buffer. People have used `xor` with two times the same value to produce a zero too, without writing a zero byte explicitly.

That's the classic way of doing it. But there are some security blocks that can tell that such things happened and other stuff that make the stack non-executable. But i guess there are way better tricks than i just explained. Some assembler guy could probably now tell you long stories about that :)

#### How to avoid it

**Always** use functions that take a maximal-length argument too, if you are not **100%** sure that a buffer is really large enough. Don't play such games as "oh, the number will not exceed 5 characters" - it will fail some day. Remember that one rocket where scientists said that the number will not exceed some magnitude, because the rocket would never be that fast. But some day, it *was* actually faster, and what resulted was an integer overflow and the rocket crashed (it's about a bug in [Ariane 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5_Flight_501), one of the most expensive Computer bugs in history).

For example, instead of gets use `fgets`. And instead of `sprintf` use `snprintf` where suitable and available (or just the C++ style things like istream and stuff)

Comment: Buffer overflow = buffer overrun?

Comment: i haven't know the latter term. wikipedia seem to say they mean the same.

Answer (score 14):

In the modern linux OS you can't made exploiting buffer overflow without some EXTRA experiment.
why ? because you will be blocked by **ASLR** (Address Stack Layer Randomization) and **stack protector** in this modern GNU C compiler. you will not locate memory easily because memory will fall into random memory caused by **ASLR**. and you will blocked by **stack protector** if you try to overflow the program.

For begining you need to put of ASLR to be 0
default value is 2

```
root@bt:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
2
root@bt:~# echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
root@bt:~# cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
0
root@bt:~#
```

in this is case not about OLD STYLE buffer overflow tutorial you may got from internet. or aleph one tutorial will not work anymore in your system now.

now lets make a program vulnerability to buffer overflow scenario

```
---------------------bof.c--------------------------
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        char buffer[400];
        strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

        return 0;
}
---------------------EOF-----------------------------
```

looks at strcpy function is dangerous without stack protector, because function without checking how many bytes we will input.
compile with extra option **-fno-stack-protector dan -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2** for take off stack protector in your C program

```
root@bt:~# gcc -g -o bof -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 bof.c
root@bt:~# chown root:root bof
root@bt:~# chmod 4755 bof
```

buffer overflow C program with SUID root access scenatio now we have make it.
now lets search how many bytes we need to put into buffer to made a program segmentation fault

```
root@bt:~# ./bof `perl -e 'print "A" x 400'`
root@bt:~# ./bof `perl -e 'print "A" x 403'`
root@bt:~# ./bof `perl -e 'print "A" x 404'`
Segmentation fault
root@bt:~#
```

you see we need 404 bytes to made program segmentation fault (crash) now how many bytes we need to overwrite **EIP** ? EIP is instruction will be executed after. so hacker do overwrite **EIP** to evil instruction what they want in the binary SUID on the program. if the program in the SUID root, the instruction will be runned in root access.

```
root@bt:~# gdb -q bof
(gdb) list
1       #include <stdio.h>
2       #include <string.h>
3
4       int main(int argc, char** argv)
5       {
6               char buffer[400];
7               strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
8
9               return 0;
10      }
(gdb) run `perl -e 'print "A" x 404'`
Starting program: /root/bof `perl -e 'print "A" x 404'`

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7e86606 in __libc_start_main () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
(gdb) run `perl -e 'print "A" x 405'`
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /root/bof `perl -e 'print "A" x 405'`

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7e800a9 in ?? () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

program GOT segmentation fault return code. let's input more bytes and take see to EIP register.

```
(gdb) run `perl -e 'print "A" x 406'`
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /root/bof `perl -e 'print "A" x 406'`

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7004141 in ?? ()
(gdb)

(gdb) run `perl -e 'print "A" x 407'`
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /root/bof `perl -e 'print "A" x 407'`

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00414141 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

little more

```
(gdb) run `perl -e 'print "A" x 408'`
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /root/bof `perl -e 'print "A" x 408'`

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x41414141 in ?? ()
(gdb)

(gdb) i r
eax            0x0      0
ecx            0xbffff0b7       -1073745737
edx            0x199    409
ebx            0xb7fc9ff4       -1208180748
esp            0xbffff250       0xbffff250
ebp            0x41414141       0x41414141
esi            0x8048400        134513664
edi            0x8048310        134513424
eip            0x41414141       0x41414141 <-- overwriten !!
eflags         0x210246 [ PF ZF IF RF ID ]
cs             0x73     115
ss             0x7b     123
ds             0x7b     123
es             0x7b     123
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x33     51
(gdb)
```

now you can do your next step...

Answer (score 10):

A buffer overflow is just writing past the end of a buffer:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char buf[10];
    memset(buf, 0, 11);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what has already been said, keep in mind that you'r program may or may not "crash" when a buffer overflow occurs. It *should* crash, and you should hope it does - but if the buffer overflow "overflows" into another address that your application has also allocated - your application may appear to operate normally for a longer period of time.

If you are using a later edition of Microsoft Visual Studio - I would suggest using the new secure counterparts in the stdlib, such as sprintf_s insted of sprintf, ect...

Comment: There is also `snprintf`, which has the advantage of being standardized (ISO C 99). There's also `asprintf` (GNU and BSD libc), `g_strdup_printf` (Glib).

Answer (score 2):

The "classic" buffer overflow example is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[10];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
}
```

That lets you play with the buffer overflow parameters and tweak them to your hearts content.  The book "[Hacking - The Art of Exploitation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593271441)" (Link goes to Amazon) goes into great detail about how to play around with buffer overflows (purely as an intellectual exercise obviously).

Answer (score 1):

This should be enought to reproduce it:

```
void buffer_overflow() 
{
    char * foo = "foo";
    char buffer[10];

    for(int it = 0; it < 1000; it++) {
        buffer[it] = '*';
    }

    char accessViolation = foo[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check you program for buffer overflows, you could run it with tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). They will find some memory management bugs for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general comment about the answers you received. For example:

> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> {
>     char buffer[10];
>     strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
> }
> ```

And:

> ```
> int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
> {
>     char buf[10];
>     memset(buf, 0, 11);
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

On modern Linux platforms, this may not work as expected or intended. It may not work because of the FORTIFY_SOURCE security feature.

FORTIFY_SOURCE uses "safer" variants of high risk functions like `memcpy` and `strcpy`. The compiler uses the safer variants when it can deduce the destination buffer size. If the copy would exceed the destination buffer size, then the program calls `abort()`.

To disable FORTIFY_SOURCE for your testing, you should compile the program with `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` or `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0`.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, a buffer is a portion of memory set aside for a particular purpose, and a buffer overflow is what happens when a write operation into the buffer keeps going past the end (writing into memory which has a different purpose). This is *always* a bug.

A buffer overflow attack is one which uses this bug to accomplish something that the program's author didn't intend to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

With the correct answers given: To get more into this topic, you might want to listen to the Podcast Security Now. In [Episode 39](http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm#39) (a while back) they discussed this in depth. This is a quick way to get a deeper understanding without requiring to digest a whole book.

(At the link you'll find the archive with multiple size versions as well as a transcript, if you're rather visually oriented). Audio is not the *perfect* medium for this topic but Steve is working wonders to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Buffer overflow is the insertion of characters beyond what the allocated memory can hold.

Comment: Does this answer add anything new compared to the already existing? Please do not repeat, upvote good answers