# how to properly assign memory to dynamic char array

Tags: c++, arrays, c-strings

I tried using malloc and new but in either case i end up with size of array to 24. What is going on?

```
//I want to copy the last nine characters to a new string
//the function is basically for copying last x number of characters to a new string. 

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "1234567890";

  int offset=1;
  int j=offset;
  int len=strlen(str);
  cout<<len-offset<<endl;

  char str[] = "1234567890";
  char* s=new char[9];


    for(int i=0;j<len;i++){
        s[i]=str[j];
        j++;
    }
 cout<<strlen(s);
return 0;
}
```

Now I am guessing that memory assigned is in bytes. but then i am assigning 9 bytes, why is it showing as 24?

Comment: where is it showing 24?

Comment: Maybe because you're walking off the end of your allocated array (which is size 9) when looping over a larger string (which is length 10), *and* you're not terminating your string with a nul-char regardless (a requirement for `strlen()` to function properly).  You program has undefined behavior on multiple locations, and frankly you're (un)lucky it didn't crash. Finally, this isn't even *compilable* code, as `str` is declared *twice* in the same scope.

Comment: The repeat declaration is a mistake while posting the code.

Answer (score 1):

I've commented your code below to show what's going on. You've got a buffer overflow situation because you're overwriting more memory than you've allocated for `s`. This causes undefined behavior. If you are unfamiliar with what a buffer overflow is, be sure to check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574159/what-is-a-buffer-overflow-and-how-do-i-cause-one). You will be a much better programmer for reading it.

```
//I want to copy the last nine characters to a new string
//the function is basically for copying last x number of characters to a new string. 

int main ()
{
  char str[] = "1234567890";

  int offset=1;
  int j=offset;
  int len=strlen(str); // len == 10
  cout<<len-offset<<endl;

  char str[] = "1234567890";
  char* s=new char[9]; // s has room for 9 bytes


    for(int i=0;j<len;i++){ // len == 10
        s[i]=str[j];
        j++;
    }
    // You've now written past the end of the memory allocated for s.
    // Welcome to undefined behavior land
 cout<<strlen(s);
return 0;
}
```