# Is this an example of a buffer overflow?

Tags: c, memory-management, buffer, buffer-overflow

The following code generated this output on my computer (Mac OS X Yosemite 64 bit architecture):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 5;
    int *q = p;
    q = *(p + 1);
    printf("p is %p\n", p);
    printf("q is %p\n", q);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
p is 0x7f8f49404c90

q is 0xffffffffb0000000
```

The second pointer is a pretty large number so I'm wondering if it is correct to say this is a buffer overflow.

Comment: did you really mean `q = *(p + 1);`? or `q = (p + 1);`

Comment: I really meant that. Incrementing the memory address by 1 and then dereferencing that.

Comment: yep, that's what. don't you mean `*q = *(p + 1);`? the result of that is a different discussion, though.

Comment: Creating a buffer overflow isn't rocket science. `int arr[1]; arr[1]=0;` There you go.

Comment: [Yes/no questions about an example are not a good fit for this site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions). Answers to such questions are rarely useful to anyone except the original asker. The purpose of this site is to create a useful repository of high quality questions with answers. Instead of asking "is this an example of _X_", ask "what is _X_".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a buffer overflow and how do I cause one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574159/what-is-a-buffer-overflow-and-how-do-i-cause-one)

Answer (score 2):

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

The memory being allocated can hold just an integer.

which you are already doing by

```
*p = 5;
```

Now you are incrementing the pointer

```
(p+1)
```

This is the memory location which you have not allocated . Now you are trying to read the data stored in (p+1) which will lead to undefined behavior as mentioned by you this is a buffer overflow.

```
*q = *(p+1)
```

and then trying to assign this value to `*q` which might cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

as per the discussion, your code should be  `*q = *(p + 1);`

<sup>Enable all the warnings in your compiler. Then,  in cases like `q = *(p + 1)`, your compilar would have warned you regarding `assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast`</sup>

Here `q` [`p + 1`] points to a memory location which is not allocated to your program. `malloc()` allocated the meemory enough to hold a single integer to `p`. In other words, you are not suppossed to access memory location after `malloc()`-ed memory region from your program. So, accessing [`p + 1`] will result in **undefined behaviour**.

You can get more insight on this if you compile your program and run it through a memory debugger , say `valgrind`. It will show you the memory region access violation.

---

EDIT:

Check the code below [line 8]

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
  4 {
  5     int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
  6     *p = 5;
  7     int *q = p;
  8     *q = *(p + 1);
  9     printf("p is %p\n", p);
 10     printf("q is %p\n", q);
 11     return 0;
 12 }
```

and the result [partial] after running thr' `valgrind`

```
==12786== Invalid read of size 4
==12786==    at 0x80483E9: main (test71.c:8)
==12786==  Address 0x402602c is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==12786==    at 0x4005903: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==12786==    by 0x80483D0: main (test71.c:5)
==12786==
```